# SAS Specific Date format

Tags: date, format, sas

I've found several questions regarding SAS dates in this forum, but i haven't been able to find the answer to this one. I think it is rather simple, but i can't get it right.

I have a data set with a date (DD-MM-YYYY) which for some reason has a Character format. I would like it to be translated into a date format (YYYY-MM-DD). I can get it to 'look' right by by separating and concatenating the parts, but, then i can't get the format right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the input() function with an appropriate informat:

`datevariable=input(textvariable,ddmmyy10.);`

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't do the job unfortunately.  
  
data y;  
set x;  
datevar=input(text,ddmmyy10.);  
run;  
  
When text=05-10-1982 i get datevar=8313.  

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: That's correct - SAS stores dates internally as days past 1st Jan 1960, so 8313 is the numeric representation of the date you want. You can output it in whatever format you want with PUT(). I suggest reading about SAS formats and informats for more details, eg here: http://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/59498.pdf